# Prism / MEF -- Once my app is running, how do I add to my AggregateCatalog later on?

Tags: dependency-injection, prism, mef, catalog

Basically, I have the following scenario:

1. User runs application
2. The Bootstrapper loads the "Modules" directory into the AggregateCatalog.
3. My navigation menu is built
4. The user clicks refresh
5. The app downloads a new module and copies it into the Module directory.

I somehow need to be able to add in the new module to my AggregateCatalog and update my navigation menu. I figure a "AllowRecomposition" is necessary, but how do I actually add the new assembly to my AggregateCatalog after my app is already running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import the AggregateCatalog you can access it from within your ViewModel (or wherever else you want to add to it.

```
[Import()]
private AggregateCatalog _aggregateCatalog;

...

private void SomeFunc()
{
    _aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(...);
}
```

---

NOTE: If the Assembly would affect any Import or ImportMany statements, they must allow for recomposition or you will get an exception. For example, if your assembly contains another `IFooService` export...

```
//Exception Thrown
[ImportMany(typeof(IFooService))]
private IEnumerable<IFooService> _myFooServices;

//No Exception Thrown
[ImportMany(typeof(IFooService), AllowRecomposition = true)]
private IEnumerable<IFooService> _myFooServices;
```

---

NOTE: You will trigger `OnImportsSatisfied` if you implemented the `IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification` interface again, so ensure that your application does not have issues because of this.